# How to encrypt (one way i.e. irreversible is also fine) a python script which is still executable?

Tags: python, encryption, obfuscation

I have an AI program written in Python. I want to deploy the script on Ubuntu/Windows machine without exposing the source script.
How can I encrypt the Python script so that it is irreversibly encoded but can be used as usual (say by calling `python <script_name>.py` from the terminal)?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Look on the web and on SO, there are already some answers there. It's not possible, because of the CPython interpreter works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781659/how-to-encrypt-python-source-code-on-raspberry-pi#comment72677368_42781659

Comment: You said its an 'AI' program, just let the program figure it out.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Haha, unfortunately, it's not that smart yet. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real encryption is not really possible but by obfuscation and compression you can make it pretty hard for anyone to understand- or reuse the source code. You can take a look at this: 
https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/

You can also try compiling your python script to byte-code, but all these processes are still semi-reversible if someone really wants to reverse-engineer your code.

Answer (score 3):

### Obfuscate Python Scripts

- At first, compile python source file to code objects
- Iterate code object, wrap bytecode of each code object as the
  following format

```
  
    0   JUMP_ABSOLUTE            n = 3 + len(bytecode)

    3
    ...
    ... Here it's obfuscated bytecode
    ...

    n   LOAD_GLOBAL              ? (__pyarmor__)
    n+3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
    n+6 POP_TOP
    n+7 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            0
```

- Save obfuscated code objects as .pyc or .pyo, so it can be run or
  imported by common Python interpreter.

### Run or Import Obfuscated Python Scripts

Those obfuscated file (.pyc or .pyo) can be run and imported as normal
way by common python interpreter. But when those code object is called
first time, from the wrapped bytecode descripted in above section, we
know

- First op is JUMP_ABSOLUTE, it will jump to offset n
- At offset n, the instruction is to call a PyCFunction. This function
  will restore those obfuscated bytecode between offset 3 and n, and
  place the original bytecode at offset 0
- After function call, the last instruction is to jump to
  offset 0. The really bytecode now is executed.

There is a tool [Pyarmor](https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor) to obfuscate python scripts by this way.